# Building IBM MQ C++ samples with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, ibm-mq

I have IBM MQ Client version 9.0.4.0 x64 installed on Windows 10. Is it possible to build `C++` samples from `MQ_INTALLATION_PATH\Tools\cplus\Samples` with Visual Studio 2017? There is this [article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1407_gabhane/1407_gabhane.html) on this topic, but it is for `C` samples and Visual Studio 2010.

The first problem that I have is with `include` folder. The `include` folder path for `C++` samples is `MQ_INTALLATION_PATH\Tools\cplus\include`. This folder has files with `.hpp` extensions. Some of the files from this folder have includes for files located in `MQ_INTALLATION_PATH\Tools\c\include`. For example `imqmsg.hpp` file has `#include <cmqc.h>`. Should the project have `MQ_INTALLATION_PATH\Tools\c\include` added as include directory?

Update: as recommended in comment added include directory `MQ_INTALLATION_PATH\Tools\c\include`. This results in multiple linker errors with code `LNK2019`. I'll add all configuration steps done and samples of erros below:

- New Visual C++ `Empty Project` create in Visual Studio 2017
- `MQ_INTALLATION_PATH\Tools\cplus\include` and `MQ_INTALLATION_PATH\Tools\c\include` added in Properties > VC++ Directories > Include Directories
- `MQ_INTALLATION_PATH\Tools\Lib64` added in Properties > VC++ Directories > Library Directories
- `mqm.Lib` added to Properties > Linker > Command Line > Additional Options
- `imqsget.cpp` from `MQ_INTALLATION_PATH\Tools\cplus\samples` added to Source Files

As mentioned above with such config build results in multiple linker errors:

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl ImqStr::ImqStr(char const *)" (??0ImqStr@@QEAA@PEBD@Z) referenced in function main  
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl ImqErr::~ImqErr(void)" (??1ImqErr@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl ImqMgr::`vbase destructor'(void)" (??_DImqMgr@@QEAAXXZ)        
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: static void * __cdecl ImqErr::operator new(unsigned __int64)" (??2ImqErr@@SAPEAX_K@Z) referenced in function main   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl ImqErr::operator delete(void *)" (??3ImqErr@@SAXPEAX@Z) referenced in function main$dtor$6  
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl ImqStr::ImqStr(void)" (??0ImqStr@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function main  
...
```

Comment: Yes. Add that directory

Comment: @lxop, when this directory is added the build fails with multiple linker error. I will update the question with those errors.

Comment: Wrong .lib: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q030490_.htm

Comment: @HansPassant Do you mean `lib` vs `lib64` or something else? I tried both `lib64` with x64 and `lib` with x86.

Comment: No.  mqm.lib is suitable for C programs but a C++ program requires imqb23vn.lib and imqc23vn.lib

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you, that fixed it, build succeeded. I you add it as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: Use what you learned to complete this Q+A yourself please.